# Symbols such as £ end up being Â in the database

Tags: encoding, characters

Any posts with symbols such as £ or & or ♥ end up being Â or worse. It doesn't show in the admin panel on the edit post page, but it is saved in the database as Â and shows on the actual live blog as Â too.

[Here are the relevant tables in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTjPq.jpg)

And the wp-config snippet:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8');
```

Believe me, I have tried **every single** tutorial and tip and suggestion that you can find on Google.

I realise it's a UTF8 encoding issue. But my database is UTF8. My wp-config says UTF8. I've used every plugin and SQL snippet to convert my database, tables and all posts inbetween.

Not a single thing has worked - I've been at this for 3 weeks now and I'm about to explode.

So please... somebody help me!

Comment: Please also inspect the actual tables. Just have seen an UTF-8 database that had `latin-swedish-ci` for only some of the tables.

Comment: Please list your exact configuration details. Saying database  and WordPress "are UTF8" is too vague.

Comment: @Rarst Which configuration details? Like I said, wp-config has "define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');" and the collation on everything in the database is "utf8_general_ci". I don't know what other information you need?

Comment: @kaiser I have checked them all, they are definitely all utf8_general_ci

Comment: Rarst meant that you copy/paste the details from your config file into the question. Same goes for screenshots of your tables config.

Comment: @rarst Ok, updated the post!